# How to upload a file into Request call of REST API while running Automated test cases suit in POSTMAN

Tags: java, rest, automated-tests, postman, newman

I have a REST API call, which will take **Multipart** **Data** as Content-Type with a **file**(zip,rar,etc) and **JSON Object** as parameters shown below

[The Request Structure in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OrdR.png)

Now i wanted to write an automated test script for this API to run on Postman, but facing a problem in uploading a file during the Execution of the Collections.

Kindly share any views on how to upload a file during the Test execution.

Comment: Hi @Ramavi if any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Hi @Ray, i'm trying out this, but my newman test run is failing, so trying to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be done with Newman. The Postman docs and blog explain how:

1. https://www.getpostman.com/docs/run_file_post_requests
2. http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/11/15/using-newman-to-run-collections-with-file-post-requests/

Comment: Its working now, in newman i have used -k option as well to run my collection.json and outcome was success.